# In C++ objects: Should I be casting pointers with the parent class or should I be casting with the actual class itself

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this parent class in C++

```
//ParentClass header file
public ParentClass{
public:
    ParentClass();
    virtual void someParentFunction();
private:
    //other member variables and functions
};

//Functions implemented done in respective .cpp file
```

I extended this class so I have a child that looks like this

```
//ChildOneClass header file
public ChildOneClass : public ParentClass{
public:
    //Constructors and other functions
private:
    //Other members
};

//Functions implemented in respective .cpp file
```

Example declaration:

```
//Dynamically create one ChildOneClass object
ChildOneClass * c = new ChildOneClass();

//I know this is never done, but for example purposes i just did this
void * v = c;
```

I know if you have a pointer that points to the object you can do both:

```
((ParentClass *) v)->someParentFunction();
```

or:

```
((ChildOneClass *) v)->someParentFunction();
```

But which way is the correct way? Does it matter if I cast a pointer thats pointing to the subclass as a parent class? Sorry if this is confusing please give me some feedback if the question is confusing. I'll do my best to clarify

Comment: The correct way is not to use `void *` in the first place

Comment: If you got it to work, then it is correct. Theoretically, both ways should be correct, but void pointers can cause some weird results sometimes. If you run into any problems, try a `static_cast`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I revised my example to better fit what I wanted to ask in my question.

Comment: Moses, changing your original question to a completely different one is not appropriate.  There are correct answers to your original question already posted.  Your new question is only tangentially related.  I am going to roll back your question: please post a new, different question about the grandparent/parent/child situation.

Comment: @Yakk Well this situation clearly calls for meta. Unfortunately it's down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**: This answer addresses a later revision of the original question, which has since been reverted. For an answer to the original and current revision of the question, please see [Dieter Lucking's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062904/2069064).

If you want to call `someParentFunction()` on a class which *may* have a derived class which contains that function, you'll want to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to the most base class with which that call is valid:

```
GrandParentClass *g = ...;

if (ParentClass* pc = dynamic_cast<ParentClass*>(g)) {
    // ok, it's a ParentClass, this is safe
    pc->someParentFunction();
} 
else {
    // not a ParentClass, do something else, log an error, throw, etc.
}
```

There's no reason to cast all the way down to `ChildOneClass`, since you would miss all the types that are `ParentClass` but are not `ChildOneClass`. This covers all the valid subsets. Note that `GrandParentClass` would need to be polymorphic in order for this to work (e.g. `GrandParentClass` has a `virtual` member function).

Comment: thank you. I was thinking that because i wasn't casting all the way down, there would have been some undefined behaviour

Answer (score 8):

The only correct cast of a void* to a class pointer is the cast to the original class pointer type passed to the void*. Anything else may lead to unexpected results (eg.: having virtual or multiple inheritance)

Comment: I don't think that's true. `reinterpret_cast` is even explicitly defined as two `static_cast`s to `void*` and back.

Comment: @Barry A T* cast to void* and back to the same T* is well defined.

Comment: So is a `T*` cast to `void*` cast back to `T2*`, as long as the alignment of `T` and `T2` are the same. Regardless, looks like `void*` disappeared from the question.

Comment: @Barry Alignment is no concern, but the 'beginning' of T1 or T2

Comment: Yes sorry, It was a poor decision on my part to use  void * as my example. I revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating polymorphic hierarchies you should be thinking in terms of *interfaces*. Ideally you should never need to cast. However in some cases it is necessary.

When you cast it should be to the specific *interface* that you need. So if you *need* to process objects of the derived type cast to the derived type. If you *need* to process objects of the base type cast to the base type.

Your design should make it obvious what *interface* is being dealt with at which point in the system.

If you are casting a lot (or even at all) it could be a symptom of poor design.

Comment: A T* cast to void* and back to the same T* is well defined

Comment: @DieterLücking thanks, you're right. For some reason I was thinking of function pointers, I'll fix it.